# How to select font node in Sahi?

Tags: ui-automation, sahi

I am using Sahi to record my actions in IE8. My page contains this markup:

```
<td id="ButtonText" class="myClass">
    <font title="unique title" onclick="CallThis()">ButtonText</font>
</td>
```

When I click the button defined above, Sahi records:

```
_click(_cell("Button Text"));
```

But when I play this back, the button is not clicked. However,

```
_assertExists(_cell("Button Text"));
```

returns true.

I have added the following line into the concat.js file to try to make it detect font nodes:

```
this.addAD({tag: "FONT", type: "null", event:"click", name: "_font", attributes: ["sahiText", "title|alt", "id", "index", "href", "className"], action: "_click", value: "sahiText"});
```

but this doesn't seem to have had any effect (I have restarted Sahi). I don't have any control over the page being tested and I am not sure whether the td node or the font node is being selected.

How do I fire the onclick event of the font node?

EDIT:
I have added _font to sahi/config/normal_functions.txt

Manually tweaking the page using IE tools to have the onclick even on the td results in the same steps being recorded, but it will now play it back.

```
<td id="ButtonText" class="myClass" onclick="CallThis()">
    <font title="unique title">ButtonText</font>
</td>
```

Unfortunately I am unable to make any changes to the page and I still need to playback the onclick event which exists on the font node.

Both

```
_font("ButtonText");
_font("unique title");
```

give

> [Exception] [object Error]

Comment: Worth noting that I made the change to concat.js based on http://sahi.co.in/w/tweaking-sahi-apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to remove the quotes around "null":

```
this.addAD({tag: "FONT", type: null, event:"click", name: "_font", attributes: ["sahiText", "title|alt", "id", "index", "href", "className"], action: "_click", value: "sahiText"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add _font to sahi/config/normal_functions.txt, restart Sahi and check.

Regards,
Narayan

Comment: Thanks Narayan - I really appreciate the expert advice :) 
Unfortunately I am still unable to get this to work. I have the 'this.addAD...' line in my question and have added _font to the other file as your recommended. Should I be able to get a handle on the tag as _font("Button Text")? I just get [Exception] [object Error] when I try anything using the _font prefix.

Comment: I have posted the solution to the problem as a separate answer. However, this answer did partially help me so I am going to assign the bounty to Narayan.